# Scala analogue to "with object do begin ... end" (shortcutting method access)

Tags: scala

In old rusty Pascal there were convenient construct to perform a sequence of actions on object or record:

```
with obj do
begin
  methodCall
  otherMethodCall
  ...
end
```

I'm trying to touch something similar in scala, but something missing in my head :)

Is it possible to achieve somehow such effect, as if obj was in current scope of passed closure and behaved as this:

```
{
  import obj._
  callObjMethod(x, y)
  objVal.doSomething()
  ...
}
```

But in customized syntax like:

```
doWith (obj) {
  callObjMethod(x, y)
  objVal.doSomething()
}
```

Intuitionally I feel that it's more `no` than `yes` but curiosity wants to know for sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possibility is the `tap` method:

```
def tap[A](obj: A)(actions: (A => _)*) = {
  actions.foreach { _(obj) }
  obj
}

tap(obj) (
  _.callObjMethod(x, y),
  _.objVal.doSomething()
)
```

or after using enrichment

```
implicit class RichAny[A](val obj: A) extends AnyVal {
  def tap(actions: (A => _)*) = {
    actions.foreach { _(obj) }
    obj
  }
}

obj.tap (
  _.callObjMethod(x, y),
  _.objVal.doSomething()
)
```

I think that with macros you should even be able to get your desired syntax (and avoid the overhead of creating the function objects), but I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: Cannot get how underscore becomes reference to object in `_.callObjMethod`. How?

Comment: I would call it [Kestrel](http://combinators.info/#kestrels), not RichAny, 'cause it operation comes from combinators.

Comment: @dmitry That's simply a standard shorthand for lambda expressions. `_.callObjMethod` is the same as `x => x.callObjectMethod`, and `foo(_, x)` is the same as `y => foo(y, x)`.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes, that's simply what I called it the last time I defined this class because there were other methods there as well.

Answer (score 12):

Do you mean like this?

```
val file = new java.io.File(".")

// later as long as file is in scope

{
  import file._
  println(isDirectory)
  println(getCanonicalPath())
}
```

You can just use the `import` keyword to bring the methods of the object in scope.

Comment: Yes, i mean this, and this is written in the question by the way.

Comment: This seems like the best answer (though the other one is interesting and worth upvoting).

Comment: that's not a best answer at all, just because this technique is layed out in question from the beginning, and I tried to find out how to do something to behave **like** this.

Comment: @dmitry  oh yeah that is indeed written in the question! Honestly I didn't understand that you already knew the technique even after I read the question 3 times.